# Set limit to array_agg()

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, limit

I have the following Postgres query:

```
SELECT array_agg("Esns".id ) 
FROM public."Esns", 
     public."PurchaseOrderItems" 
WHERE 
    "Esns"."PurchaseOrderItemId" = "PurchaseOrderItems".id 
    AND "PurchaseOrderItems"."GradeId"=2 
LIMIT 2;
```

The limit will affect the rows. I want it to limit the `array_agg()` to 2 items. The following query works but I get my output with each entry in quotes:

```
SELECT array_agg ("temp")  
FROM (
    SELECT "Esns".id 
    FROM public."Esns", 
         public."PurchaseOrderItems" 
    WHERE 
        "Esns"."PurchaseOrderItemId" = "PurchaseOrderItems".id 
        AND "PurchaseOrderItems"."GradeId"=2 
    LIMIT 4
) as "temp" ;
```

This give me the following output

```
{(13),(14),(15),(12)}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
select id[1], id[2]
from (
    SELECT array_agg("Esns".id ) as id
    FROM public."Esns", 
         public."PurchaseOrderItems" 
    WHERE 
        "Esns"."PurchaseOrderItemId" = "PurchaseOrderItems".id 
        AND "PurchaseOrderItems"."GradeId"=2 
) s
```

or if you want the output as array you can [slice](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) it:

```
SELECT (array_agg("Esns".id ))[1:2] as id_array
FROM public."Esns", 
     public."PurchaseOrderItems" 
WHERE 
    "Esns"."PurchaseOrderItemId" = "PurchaseOrderItems".id 
    AND "PurchaseOrderItems"."GradeId"=2
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The second answer is what i was looking for as i do want an array and i want to be able to dynamically set the upper bound on the limit. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The parentheses (not "quotes") in the result are decorators for the **row** literals. You are building an array of whole rows (which happen to contain only a single column). Instead, aggregate only the **column**.

Also, direct [array construction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) from a query result is typically simpler and faster:

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT e.id 
   FROM   public."Esns" e
   JOIN   public."PurchaseOrderItems" p ON p.id = e."PurchaseOrderItemId"
   WHERE  p."GradeId" = 2 
   --  ORDER BY ???
   LIMIT  4  -- or 2?
   )
```

You need to `ORDER BY` something if you want a stable result and / or pick certain rows. Otherwise the result is arbitrary and can change with every next call.

While being at it I rewrote the query with explicit JOIN syntax, which is generally preferable, and used table aliases to simplify.

Comment: Are there cases where `array` constructor won't work and `array_agg` is needed? Constructor is able to replace all uses of `array_agg` that I have. Is there an equivalent constructor for json that could simplify or replace `json_agg`?

Comment: @user779159: Yes: Multiple array aggregations in the same `SELECT` list, Possibly with differing per-aggregate sort order.) JSON: no, but you can use ` to_jsonb(ARRAY(...))`.