# Adding LIMIT to ARRAY_TO_JSON or ARRAY_AGG

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-json, array-agg

In a 2-player game using PostgreSQL 9.6.6 as backend I have defined the following custom stored function for retrieving chat messages for a user:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_user_chat(
                in_uid integer
        ) RETURNS jsonb AS
$func$
        SELECT COALESCE(
                JSONB_OBJECT_AGG(gid, ARRAY_TO_JSON(y)),
                '{}'::jsonb
        ) FROM (
                SELECT  c.gid,
                        ARRAY_AGG(
                                JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                                        'created', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM c.created)::int,
                                        'uid',     c.uid,
                                        'msg',     c.msg
                                )
                                ORDER BY c.created ASC
                        ) AS y
                FROM      words_chat c
                LEFT JOIN words_games g
                USING     (gid)
                WHERE     in_uid in (g.player1, g.player2)
                AND       (g.finished IS NULL OR g.finished > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day')
                GROUP BY  c.gid
                /* LIMIT 10 */
        ) AS x;

$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

It joins words_games and words_chat tables and produces the following JSON-object (with game id "9" as a string key) holding a JSON-array with messages:

```
 # select words_get_user_chat(6);



                                                                                                                   words_get_user_chat                        




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"9": [{"msg": "test2", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445342}, {"msg": "test3", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445358}, {"msg": "test4", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445369
}, {"msg": "test5", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445381}, {"msg": "test6", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445405}, {"msg": "test7", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445415}, {"
msg": "test8", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445508}, {"msg": "test9", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445539}, {"msg": "test10", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445743}, {"msg"
: "test11", "uid": 6, "created": 1516445989}, {"msg": "test12", "uid": 6, "created": 1516446101}, {"msg": "test13", "uid": 6, "created": 1516446125}, {"msg": 
"test14", "uid": 6, "created": 1516446145}, {"msg": "test15", "uid": 6, "created": 1516446227}, {"msg": "test16", "uid": 6, "created": 1516446652}, {"msg": "t
est17", "uid": 6, "created": 1516446999}, {"msg": "test18", "uid": 6, "created": 1516447168}, {"msg": "test19", "uid": 6, "created": 1516447229}, {"msg": "tes
t20", "uid": 6, "created": 1516447493}, {"msg": "test21", "uid": 6, "created": 1516447532}, {"msg": "test22", "uid": 6, "created": 1516447555}, {"msg": "test2
3", "uid": 6, "created": 1516448017}, {"msg": "test24", "uid": 6, "created": 1516448062}]}
(1 row)
```

This works well, but I would like to add `LIMIT 10` to the number of array elements - as a measure against chat flooding.

I have tried adding it to the function (please see the commented line above), but it had no effect.

Could you please suggest the correct spot for `LIMIT 10`?

I send the JSON-objects over WebSockets to Android app and would like to prevent malicious users from blowing up the size of such objects by flooding chats.

**UPDATE:**

I am trying Mike's suggestion:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_user_chat(
                in_uid integer
        ) RETURNS jsonb AS
$func$
        SELECT COALESCE(
                JSONB_OBJECT_AGG(gid, ARRAY_TO_JSON(y)),
                '{}'::jsonb
        ) FROM (
                SELECT  c.gid,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.gid) AS rn,
                        ARRAY_AGG(
                                JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                                        'created', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM c.created)::int,
                                        'uid',     c.uid,
                                        'msg',     c.msg
                                )
                                ORDER BY c.created ASC
                        ) AS y
                FROM      words_chat c
                LEFT JOIN words_games g
                USING     (gid)
                WHERE     in_uid in (g.player1, g.player2)
                AND       (g.finished IS NULL OR g.finished > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day')
                AND       rn < 10
                GROUP BY  c.gid
        ) AS x;

$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

but unfortunately get the syntax error:

```
ERROR:  42703: column "rn" does not exist
LINE 24:                 AND       rn < 10
                                   ^
LOCATION:  errorMissingColumn, parse_relation.c:3194
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here are the both tables I use, sorry for not including that info before -

```
#\d words_chat
                                   Table "public.words_chat"
 Column  |           Type           |                        Modifiers                         
---------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 cid     | bigint                   | not null default nextval('words_chat_cid_seq'::regclass)
 created | timestamp with time zone | not null
 gid     | integer                  | not null
 uid     | integer                  | not null
 msg     | text                     | not null
Indexes:
    "words_chat_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (cid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "words_chat_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "words_chat_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE

# \d words_games
                                   Table "public.words_games"
  Column  |           Type           |                         Modifiers                         
----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 gid      | integer                  | not null default nextval('words_games_gid_seq'::regclass)
 created  | timestamp with time zone | not null
 finished | timestamp with time zone | 
 player1  | integer                  | not null
 player2  | integer                  | 
 played1  | timestamp with time zone | 
 played2  | timestamp with time zone | 
 state1   | text                     | 
 state2   | text                     | 
 hint1    | text                     | 
 hint2    | text                     | 
 score1   | integer                  | not null
 score2   | integer                  | not null
 hand1    | character(1)[]           | not null
 hand2    | character(1)[]           | not null
 pile     | character(1)[]           | not null
 letters  | character(1)[]           | not null
 values   | integer[]                | not null
 bid      | integer                  | not null
Indexes:
    "words_games_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (gid)
Check constraints:
    "words_games_check" CHECK (player1 <> player2)
    "words_games_score1_check" CHECK (score1 >= 0)
    "words_games_score2_check" CHECK (score2 >= 0)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "words_games_bid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES words_boards(bid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "words_games_player1_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player1) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "words_games_player2_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (player2) REFERENCES words_users(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "words_chat" CONSTRAINT "words_chat_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_moves" CONSTRAINT "words_moves_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "words_scores" CONSTRAINT "words_scores_gid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (gid) REFERENCES words_games(gid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: use `select ... from (select *, row_number() over(partition by c.gid) as RN from .....) X where RN<10 group by gid`

Comment: Thanks Mike, but unfortunately I am not sure how to apply your suggestion - please see the update

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HLWm6ZHZ  So is suitable?  And need add ORDER BY: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.gid ORDER BY xxxx)` for get latest or other need records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should work like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_user_chat(in_uid integer)
  RETURNS jsonb AS
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE
$func$
SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_object_agg(gid, y), '{}')
FROM  (
   SELECT gid, jsonb_agg((SELECT j FROM (SELECT created, uid, msg) j)) AS y
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT gid  -- DISTINCT may be redundant
      FROM   words_games
      WHERE (finished IS NULL
          OR finished > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day'))
      AND    in_uid IN (player1, player2)
      ) g
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created)::int AS created
           , uid
           , msg
      FROM   words_chat c
      WHERE  c.gid = g.gid
      ORDER  BY c.created DESC
      LIMIT  10                        --  HERE !!
      ) c 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) x
$func$;
```

Do not aggregate all rows, just to discard the surplus later. Would be a waste. Place the `LIMIT` after `ORDER BY` in a subquery.

You need to identify qualifying `gid` from `words_games` first for this and then use a `LATERAL` join to a subquery on `words_chat`. Should be correct and faster, too.

Since `c.created` is defined `NOT NULL`, you don't need to add `NULLS LAST` in the `ORDER BY` clause. This matching multicolumn index should yield best read performance:

```
CREATE INDEX ON words_chat(gid, created DESC);
```

And maybe some index on `words_games`. Depends on cardinalities and value frequencies.

While being at it, I also streamlined construction the `jsonb` result.

Related:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)
- [Query with LEFT JOIN not returning rows for count of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467624/query-with-left-join-not-returning-rows-for-count-of-0/15468034#15468034)
- [Explain JOIN vs. LEFT JOIN and WHERE condition performance suggestion in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876673/explain-join-vs-left-join-and-where-condition-performance-suggestion-in-more-de/24876797#24876797)

Comment: This works flawlessly, thanks! Do you think I should add an index for the `created` column, because I use `ORDER BY` it? (I have updated my question with the desc of both tables).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498037/7821979) answers your question. Try doing:

```
(ARRAY_AGG( /* same as before */ ))[1:10] AS y
```

Comment: Works, but substantially more expensive than necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns the oldest chat messages (the 1 to 10) while I'd need the most recent 10

Comment: Then change the `ORDER BY` to `DESC`

Comment: Hmm then I have to sort it in my Android app, which didn't I want to do... I would prefer to [get a slice](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) from the end of a PostgreSQL array, but haven't found a way yet: the test `select (ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6])[-3:];` does not work as I would expect it...