# Return multiple values in Subquery in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

Question is regarding `Subquery` and `ArrayAgg` in Django ORM.

For example I have 2 models without any relationship one to another:

```
class Example1(models.Model):
    ident = Integerfield()

class Example2(models.Model):
    ident = IntegerField()
    email = EmailField()
```

There is no connection between 2 models like FK, M2M, O2O, but field
`ident` might be same integer in both models (which is a connection in a way)and in general for 1 instance of `Example1` there are multiple instances of `Example2` with same `ident`.

I want to make a `subquery` or `arrayagg` (db Postgres) or any way outside RAWSQL to make an annotation like this:

```
Example1.objects.annotate(
cls2=Subquery(
Example2.objects.filter(
ident=OuterRef(‘ident’
).values_list(‘email’, flat=True).

#or

Example1.objects.annotate(
cls2=StringAgg(
something here???, 
delimeter=’, ‘,
 distinct=True,)
```

Sure that this does not  work as `Subquery` returns multiple rows and it seems like it impossible to use  `StringAgg` as we dont have any connections between models(nothing to put inside  `StringAgg`).

Any ideas how to annotate  `Example1` with emails from  `Example2` in one queryset?

This will be used in CASE expression.

Thanks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For MySQL backend, you can use GroupConcat of [django-mysql](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html?highlight=GroupConcat#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat), or take a look on [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340684/group-concat-equivalent-in-django) to make a aggregate function youself:

```
from django_mysql.models import GroupConcat
Example1.objects.annotate(
    cls2=Subquery(
        Example2.objects.filter(ident=OuterRef('ident')).values('ident')\
        .annotate(emails=GroupConcat('email')).values('emails')
    )
)
```

For PostgreSQL backend, you can use [ArrayAgg or StringAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg, StringAgg
Example1.objects.annotate(
    cls2=Subquery(
        Example2.objects.filter(ident=OuterRef('ident')).values('ident')\
        .annotate(emails=ArrayAgg('email')).values('emails')
    )
)
# or
Example1.objects.annotate(
    cls2=Subquery(
        Example2.objects.filter(ident=OuterRef('ident')).values('ident')\
        .annotate(emails=StringAgg('email', ',')).values('emails')
    )
)
```

Comment: It works.Good answer, thanks a lot, although i dont fully understand a logic behind first values('ident').

Comment: it means to group by ident field.

Comment: This works amazing, thank you! I have pretty similar issue, but I want Array agg to return not all the related values, but for example first 5. Maybe you know how to do it?
I've seen this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497607/set-limit-to-array-agg
And you can do a slice, but I don't understand how to do it in django ORM. Maybe you know? @Blackdoor 
p.s. I want to do slice/limit in sql not in python code