# Limit length of array_agg in Athena Presto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Can you limit `array_agg` in AWS athena? In postgres you can use this syntax, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497607/set-limit-to-array-agg).

```
SELECT 
    key
    , array_agg(value LIMIT 100) as values
FROM table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use *slice* to do it:

```
SELECT 
    key
    , slice(array_agg(value),1,100) as values
FROM table
```

Please note that the array index starts at 1